# Внутренние тени slick-slider

Tags: css, html5, slick.js

**Нужно сделать внутренние тени в `slick-slider`, как показано на рисунке:**

[image: inner-shadows]

Пример разметки
`

```
    <div id="tabs_slider">
      <div class="tabs_slider_slide">
        <img src="#" alt="">
        <p>Ковры</p>
      </div>
      <div class="tabs_slider_slide">
        <img src="#" alt="">
        <p>Ковролин</p>
      </div>
      <div class="tabs_slider_slide">
        <img src="#" alt="">
        <p>Линолеум</p>
      </div>
      <div class="tabs_slider_slide">
        <img src="#" alt="">
        <p>Гарячие предложения</p>
      </div>
      <div class="tabs_slider_slide">
        <img src="#" alt="">
        <p>Грязезащита</p>
      </div>
      <div class="tabs_slider_slide">
        <img src="#" alt="">
        <p>Ламинат</p>
      </div>
      <div class="tabs_slider_slide">
        <img src="#" alt="">
        <p>Искусственная трава</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>`
```

Когда пытаюсь дать внутреннюю тень `#tabs_slider` - она ложится под слайды, а не на них, если же добавить в слайдер пустой элемент, спозиционировать абсолютно и дать `z-index: 999`, этот элемент слайдер всё равно воспринимает как слайд.
Возможно в `slick` есть встроенный функционал для таких задач, о котором я не подозреваю, других решений на ум не приходит.

Comment: в slick такое делается просто кастомизацией стрелок. Делаете их нужными по высоте и ширине и псевдоселектором ставите фон градиентом или тенью

Answer (score 3):

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #272727;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: white;
}

.tabs {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 180px;
}

img,
p,
.shadow {
  position: absolute;
  width: 300px;
  height: 180px;
}

.shadow {
  box-shadow: inset -64px 0px 66px -2px white;
}
```

```html
<div class="tabs">
  <img src="https://im0-tub-ru.yandex.net/i?id=6f8bae22480f820d4b2b3dcfbe491450&n=13">
  <p>Ковры</p>
  <div class="shadow"></div>
</div>
```